# nltk PunktSentenceTokenizer: tokenize sentences without whitespace in between

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, tokenize

Is it possible to make the [NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/) [PunktSentenceTokenizer](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.punkt.html#nltk.tokenize.punkt.PunktSentenceTokenizer) to split sentences that do not have whitespace between each other?

```py
from nltk.tokenize.punkt import PunktSentenceTokenizer

sent_tokenizer = PunktSentenceTokenizer()
print(sent_tokenizer.tokenize('Sky is blue.Metal is black.'))

'''
Output:

['Sky is blue.Metal is black.']
'''
```